# Magento product is not showing in the category

Tags: magento, categories

This is the weirdest problem that I had with magento so far.
I've been using magento for 5 months now.

so I have one category with 4 sub-category. In one of the sub-category listed 62 products.
From the back end of that category listed 62 products, every product is configurable with simple products in it set to not showing individually

So when I check the back end it is 62 products showing also on the front end, BUT on the front end some product are not showing, how come it is 62? because some products show up twice to replace the one that was not showing

I refresh and re-index a lot just to make sure, sometimes the product that didn't show up, suddenly shows up but other product that was showed up, disappear. and sometimes, products on that category change position, for example sometimes the first product on that category is A, then next time I browse through that category the first product is B

what could be the problem? how can I fix this thing

Comment: Using any custom modules ?

Comment: yes just some left banner, showing up images on the left column and custom newsletter nothing fancy, really.  One other thing is that I messed up the product data by importing csv files in excel and then had all items deleted and re-input it back manually one by one